# Jenkins and only build feature branches?

Tags: git, jenkins

In Jenkins 1.605 I have configured the following Branch Specifier for Git SCM

```
features/**
```

And a SCM poll interval at 1 minute.

But when i push changes on my feature branch:

```
 git push origin features/sample
```

Nothing happens. If I trigger the build manually `master` is build:

```
Seen branch in repository origin/features/sample
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Checking out Revision e2d7371a4e8480dcacbd2af93c2347d4b75fde19 (origin/master)
```

Have I configured the branch specifier incorrectly?

Seems to be a bug (still open):
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27352

Comment: The Git plugin 2.4.0 released 40 minutes ago should resolve this. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if giving a branch spec as a parameter works better.

That was the approach illustrated in [JENKINS-14276](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14276):

> - a parameterized build with parameter "`Branch`", default "`**`"
> - Git SCM with branch specifier "`${Branch}`"
> - SCM polling activated

In your case, you would pass as a parameter `features/**`, and see if it works better.

---

The OP confirms in the comments it does not work for now (March 2015), as mentioned in [bug JENKINS-27352](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27352):

> ### Git SCM polling is not triggered from a push notification with a parametrized branchspec

There is a PR (Pull Request) in progress: [`pull/309`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/309), not yet merged In Jenkins master.

**Update July 2015**: That PR is now closed, and the [Jenkins- 27352](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27352) now includes:

> **Fix included in [git plugin 2.4.0](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) released [18 July 2015](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/releases)**

(40 minutes ago, so give it a day before that version is visible as an upgrade in your Jenkins)

Comment: Tried doing as you described with a string build parameter but it has no effect after pushing to the feature branch. Triggering the build manually  does seem to pick up the change on the feature branch now - but also  everything matching ** which is not what I want. Looks like it will be fixed by this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27352

Comment: @u123 yes, I meant in your case using a `features/**`, not `**`. I have voted 27352.

Comment: That still does not trigger a poll using features/** - hence the bug 27352. I guess I can close the question since the answer is that its a bug?

Comment: @u123 indeed ("close" as in "accept", don't delete the question). I will monitor this bug: I have aded the link in the answer for more visibility, as well as the PR (Pull Request) currently in progress.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem
I would like to build all features branch

on jenkins version 2.46.1

all branch build work with

**/features/*